# Aren't all eigenvalues of $T^*T$ non-negative? (Clarification regarding the definition of singular values)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, singular-values

I'm having some confusion with the definition of the singular value of a matrix. As per Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, in particular functional analysis, the singular values, or s-numbers of a compact operator $T : X \to Y$ acting between Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$, are the square roots **of non-negative eigenvalues of the self-adjoint operator $T^*T$** (where $T^*$ denotes the adjoint of $T$).

But we know that the adjoint of a matrix $T$ [coincides with its complex-conjugate transpose matrix](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Adjoint_matrix) $T^\dagger$. We also know that the eigenvalues of $T^\dagger$ as precisely [complex conjugates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3436179/978567) of the eigenvalues of $T$. Moreover, we know that the eigenvalues of $T^\dagger T$ are non-negative as [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3436179/978567).

So if all eigenvalues of $T^\dagger T$ are already non-negative, then why does Wikipedia bother to consider square roots of only **non-negative eigenvalues** of $T^*T$? **Aren't all eigenvalues of $T^*T$ non-negative in general, or am I missing something?** (Here's a related question: [Proving that the eigenvalues of $T^*T$ is non-negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596742/proving-that-the-eigenvalues-of-tt-is-non-negative.))

Comment: Yes, eigen values of $T^{*}T$ are all non-negative. What si intended is " ...square roots of eigen values of $T^{*}T$, which are necessarily non-negative"

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you. So Wikipedia mentioning "non-negative eigenvalues" specifically in the definition of singular values is redundant, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you said are right. Wikipedia is redundant but not wrong.
The proof that the eigenvalues of $T^*T$ are all nonnegative should be more straightforward without picking basis or establishing the matrix form of $T^*$. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $v$ of $T^*T$, then $$(T^*Tv, v)_X = (Tv, Tv)_Y\ge 0, \text{ also }(T^*Tv, v)_X = \lambda (v, v)_X$$ hence $$\lambda = \frac{(Tv, Tv)_Y}{(v,v)_X}\ge 0$$

Comment: Thanks, I just pushed an edit to Wikipedia pointing to your answer. Feel free to improve the page further if you'd like!